# is it correct to say "hold the toy fan blade-away"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

The person in the picture above "**is holding the knife pointy-end down**" and I think "**pointy-end down**" is an adverb.

[image]

The person in the picture above "**is holding the knife pointy-end up**" and "**pointy-end up**" is an adverb.

Now I have a toy fan that looks like this

[image]

I am not sure  **if the plastic tube above is called the blade of the toy fan?**

The fan has a motor that spins the blade.

When the baby cries, I turn on the fan to let him stop crying. But I want to hold the fan in such a way that the blade facing away from the baby

[image]

Can I say "**hold the toy fan blade-away, not blade-face-in **" the same way we say "**hold the knife pointy-end down, not pointy-end up**" with "**blade-away**" and "**blade-face-in**" as adverbs?

Comment: The blades of a fan are the vanes that turn, not the "shaft, body, motor, axle". Note that "pointy-end-down" is just an easily-understood nonce term. Your suggested nonce terms "blade away" or "blade-face-in" are similar, except they're not so reminiscent of "baby talk". I'm tempted to suggest say *Hold the fan with the blades **facing away from the baby*** (so there's no danger of those blades injuring the baby), but unless the fan is *reversible*, that implies it'll simply be drawing air ***away*** from the baby's face (where blowing air ***towards*** it would have a greater cooling effect).

Comment: To talk of a knife's 'pointy end' is to use baby talk. A knife may or may not have a **point*".

Comment: Yes, you can call the 'plastic tubes' blades because they represent the flat, sharp-edged blades of a real electric fan. You hold a knife **with the point downwards**.

Comment: ["Stick them with the pointy end"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pointy_End) has become a bit of a meme since Game of Thrones.

Comment: "hold the knife with the pointed end down" is a perfectly ordinary and grammatical sentence, whereas a hyphenated "blade-away" is a new construction, following the grammar rules of some unknown foreign language.  Although, you could say in English "Hold the blade away from (whatever)", without a hyphen.